# Copied MySQL db without the ib_logfile(s) and getting "table doesn't exist in engine" error

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a local wordpress install and had to reinstall mySQL and used a backup of one of my databases but I never backed up the ib_logfile(s). Now that I have everything up and running, when I attempt to use this db I am getting this error. Any way to salvage my db without the ib_logfile(s)?

Comment: how did you backup the database in the first place? MySQL backup is normally collection of SQL queries.

Comment: I literally copied the db folder from the data folder from mySQL. Very poor backup -- I know. Learned my lesson.

Comment: check these links it may help [Salvaging inaccessible MySQL db without InnoDB log files](http://serverfault.com/questions/657829/salvaging-inaccessible-mysql-db-without-innodb-log-files) and [Repairing Corrupted Innodb on MySQL without losing any data](https://www.gcsdstaff.org/roodhouse/?p=3070). btw always use `mysqldump` to backup (easiest)

Comment: Taking a look at these now.